# Is there an option to cleanup after ALL tests in class are complete?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I tried a deinit method in my test class, however it isn't called. Using Xcode 13.3

Comment: "tried a deinit method in my test class, however it isn't called" Correct. Test classes are not deinitialized. In fact, they are initialized multiple times: once per test method that is run. All those instances persist simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XCTestCase` has a class method [`tearDown()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496280-teardown)  which is called when all tests in the class are finished:

```
override class func tearDown() {
   super.tearDown()
   // Cleanup
}
```